# How to create a blackboard math operator as \bbsum, \bbprod, \bbint, ...?

Tags: math-operators, blackboard

I'd like to create a blackboard math operator as \bbsum, \bbprod, \bbint, ... ?
I don't know where to begin. Could someone help me?
Thank you so much
Best regards.
Puck

**First Edit:** I'm trying with `\usepackage{bbold}` but the result is ugly. How can I improve?

Comment: The traditional approach is to use the metafont program.  A quick and dirty solution is to draw the symbol using TikZ.  OTOH, be sure to check The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List (CTAN).

Comment: Ok, thank you. But how?

Comment: font design isn't really on topic here and is a very different skill and toolset to typesetting

Comment: I've never actually used Metafont.  TikZ has a manual, and you can Google CTAN (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en).

Comment: Ok thank you all

Comment: Do you *really* want to do this? My sense is that any choice to add some new symbol to the mathematical language is questionable (as a point of fact, good mathematical writing style generally calls for preferring words over symbols, e.g., “for all *x* in *X*” over “∀*x*∊*X*” to choose a trivial example).

Comment: In my opinion, blackboard bold fonts should be used … when writing on blackboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that below suggestion is not a good idea, but it works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand*{\fancy}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{#1}}

\newcommand{\bbint}{\fancy{$\displaystyle\int$}}
\newcommand{\bbsum}{\fancy{$\displaystyle\sum$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\bbint\qquad \bbsum
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn’t that be a good idea?

Comment: I thought some legends like `egreg` `David Carlisle` and `Ulrike Fischer`, (so many legends etc.), may give better suggestion than this, so only I said like that...

Comment: Well, none of them have provided an alternative answer. So perhaps they were satisfied with yours. Or perhaps they had other things to do. Who knows. `;-)`